# Sumar días a fecha y generar la nueva fecha en un input text

Tags: php, javascript

Cómo puedo hacer para sumar el `input` días de pago con la fecha de salida y luego de sumarlo que me imprima la nueva fecha en otro `input`.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>Fecha de Salida:</td>
    <td><input name="fecha_sali" id="fecha_sali" type="date"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Días del Pago:</td>
    <td><input name="pago" id="pago" type="text" value="<?php echo $terms_p; ?>" ></td>
</select>
</tr>
</table>

<p>Nueva fecha de pago.</p>
<input name="pago" id="nuevafecha" type="text">
```

> NOTA: la variable `$terms_p` trae automáticamente la cantidad de días
>   desde la base de datos, por ejemplo: 60

tengo entendido que puedo hacer esa suma de días a la fecha de salida con `Javascript`, si es así de que manera podría hacerlo?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta usar javascript, puedes tomar el valor "fecha_sali" convertirlo a fecha y sumar un entero que represente los dias. Al sumar enteros a una fecha automaticamente se les interpreta como dias.

agrega un bloque de codigo javascript y ponlo segun tu preferencia en una funcion o como codigo a ejecutar al cargar la pagina...

```js
var dias = parseInt(document.getElementById("pago").value);
var fecha = Date.parse(document.getElementById("fecha_sali").value) + dias;
document.getElementById("nuevafecha").value = fecha;
```

Comment: Listo muchas gracias.